World Globe Recommendations
I hope this is the right place to ask this...
I'm looking to buy a world globe. Before I do, I want to know a few things and I'm hoping some folks can weigh in here:

Are there makers of world globes that you'd recommend?
What things should I look for to determine quality like accuracy, materials, weight, legibility, etc.?
Are there different globes that have different information on them? This is to help better my search.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!
